# opening emacs buffer in new horizontal or vertical split window using helm

Tags: emacs, spacemacs, ido, emacs-helm

How would I bind a key to open up a buffer or file in helm in a new vertical or horizontal split? (BTW, I'm using spacemacs).

With `ido` I use the handy [ido-other-window](https://github.com/gvalkov/ido-other-window/blob/master/ido-other-window.el) package to open existing buffers or files in the `ido` list to new window splits. For example, instead of pressing `RET` to open in a new window `C-2` the buffer/file will be opened in a vertical split.

Comment: What is wrong with default `C-x 1/2/3`?

Comment: I just tried `C-x ...` but that didn't work so maybe this is more of a `spacemacs` question.

Answer (score 3):

In the Helm popup, you can open a buffer in a new window using <kbd>F3</kbd> or <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>.

Press <kbd>C-z</kbd> for the full list of possible actions.